# How to check for value in Firebase that is held under a autoID child?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

Upon the tap of a delete button. I am trying to delete a particular child out of my Firebase database. My problem is that I am unable to refer to the particular `childByAutoId` in my database therefore my application does not know what child to remove.

Firebase Database

[image: Firebase Database]

DataServices File

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import UIKit

let DB_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("laboratory")        //contains the root of our database
let STORAGE_BASE = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

class DataService {

static let ds = DataService()

//DB References
private var _REF_BASE = DB_BASE
private var _REF_STATION = DB_BASE.child("stations")
private var _REF_USERS = DB_BASE.child("users")


//Storage Reference
private var _REF_ITEM_IMAGE = STORAGE_BASE.child("item-pics")

var REF_BASE: FIRDatabaseReference {

    return _REF_BASE

}

var REF_STATION: FIRDatabaseReference {

    return _REF_STATION

}

var REF_USERS: FIRDatabaseReference {

    return _REF_USERS

}

var REF_ITEM_IMAGES: FIRStorageReference {

    return _REF_ITEM_IMAGE

}

//creating a new user into the firebase database

func createFirebaseDBUser(_ uid: String, userData: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    REF_USERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(userData)
}

}
```

The information that I am trying to Delete is out of a `tableViewCell`. I have tried appending out the keys to an array but I am still unable to access the appropriate child to delete.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!), commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) {

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let currentStation = station.title
    let stationRef = DataService.ds.REF_STATION.child(currentStation!)
    let inventoryRef = stationRef.child("inventory")

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") {action in

            //delete items from firebase


            self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)

    }

    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action in



    }

    return [deleteAction, editAction]
}
```

I have found no information online about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do *you* know which child you want removed? i.e. I want to remove a child 'favorite_food:' whose value is 'pizza'.

Comment: I would like to remove the whole child. For example -KWKZGKMTjwkyjpQtwPn and all its contents

Comment: Based on what parameter? What makes that child node need to be deleted? Was it because it met/didnt meet a criteria? Because it's value was 'pizza'? Because the user swiped to delete it? You need to think through what is the cause of the node to be deleted. Once we know that, we'll have an answer.

Comment: @Jay he wants to remove it because a user deletes the item in the tableView.

Comment: @ChandlerLong where are you populating your tableView with the children in the `inventory` node?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simplified structure

```
-Uiiasidasod
   item_name: "iMac"
-Yiimamsmdd
   item_name: "MacBook"
```

A typical design pattern is to read these items from Firebase and store them in an array of dictionaries. That array is used as a *datasource* for the tableViews.

each dictionary is a key:value pair.

So the first node from above has a Firebase key (parent node name of "Uiiasidasod" and a value of "item_name: iMac"  (note the value is a dictionary as well)

```
myArray[0] = ["Uiiasidasod": "item_name: 'iMac'"]
myArray[1] = ["Yiimamsmdd": "item_name: 'MacBook'"]
```

so when the user swipes row 1 in the table, you fetch the dictionary from the array, row 1. You get the key portion (the Firebase node name) and can then delete it from Firebase.