# Deleting an object in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a bars table and want to delete a single bar from it using the storage images of that bar. Im using the bar's name to delete the bar.

> The bar name is unique - I query the name of the bar before adding a new bar to make sure no two bars have the same name.

This is my function and how i do it. I have an issue in deleting the bar object from the db. Of course when I did it this way it deleted the whole table of bars. Is there a way to get the key or the id of the autoId of the bar to be able to delete it. What is the right way to do it.

```
    func deleteBar(name:String ,completion:@escaping (_ status:Bool, _ msg:String?)->() )
{
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: dbURL).child("bars").child(name)
    storage = FIRStorage.storage()

   // print(key)

    let locationRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: dbURL).child("bar_locations")
    //delete from bars
    ref.parent?.removeValue() //This deleted the whole bars table
    //delete from location
    locationRef.child(name).removeValue()

    let storageRef = storage?.reference(forURL: storageURL).child("bars").child(name).child("logo.jpg")
    storageRef?.delete(completion: { (err) in

        if err == nil {

            completion(true, "Deleted")

        } else {
            //print(err?.localizedDescription ?? <#default value#>)
            completion(false, err?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You can store a reference or path to the storage data in Firebase database. Also, check out [Delete Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/delete-files)

Comment: @Jay My issue is not in deleting file in my storage. The issue is deleting an object in my bars table. The bars table consist of ids of bars and every id has attributes like the bar name the bar category ect... The point is that i want to know the id of a bar name to be able to delete it.

Comment: The question says *Deleting an object in firebase* so it's assumed you want to delete an object in firebase. if the question is how to delete an object from a table (I assume you have a table in code?) you should update your question. If you asking how to get the parent node name, see the answer to [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876616/how-to-check-for-value-in-firebase-that-is-held-under-a-autoid-child?noredirect=1#comment68990882_40876616). It's an unrelated question but the answer shows an example of the design patter you may want to use.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the link. It helped a lot. Seemed like i was ignoring totally the key of each node (bar) and i was depending only on the name of the bar. This was totally wrong i can say. Now im depending totally on the unique key and using it to name my locations nodes and also the images folder name of each bar. And my delete func is functional too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this great tutorial. The video is on exactly how to do this w/ Firebase in Swift. You should check out the whole playlist too:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkHEEhftUk0&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq&index=22